# Why does getaddrinfo require 3 headers?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, unix, networking

Whenever I see `getaddinfo()` used, I've seen it come alongside 3 headers:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
```

Also, [the documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getaddrinfo) groups this function alongside 2 others and lists the same 3 headers.  Why does it appear that `getaddrinfo()` requires 3 headers -- or at the very least, how can we figure out which ones are actually necessary for the function?

Comment: Try deleting some and seeing if your code compiles.

Comment: (a) Because they are all necessary. (b) See (a).

Comment: Probably the other two are for some of the members of `struct addrinfo`, like `struct sockaddr`. Since `struct addrinfo` contains a pointer to `struct sockaddr`, it can treat it as an incomplete type in the *header*, and so the header doesn't need to include `sys/socket.h`, even if the implementation file would have to. But *you* will have to include `sys/socket.h` to work with such a thing, if `netdb.h` does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have cited the documentation in your question, the answer is you should always code to how the interface is documented. Since it is documented to require these three headers, those headers should be included when using the interface.

As to the particulars, the `getaddrinfo()` API is defined in the `<netdb.h>` header file, but that header file defines some other structures and APIs that depend on `<sys/socket.h>` which depends on `<sys/types.h>`.

You may think this is silly, but it is at least documented, and you know where to find the documentation. So, resolving these dependencies is much easier that in projects that have such dependencies but fail to document them. For poorly documented systems (and even well documented ones) it is usually easier to use header files that are self-contained, but UNIX and Linux are quite old and stable systems, which tend to follow the "ain't broke, won't fix" rule.

Comment: Why doesn't `<netdb.h>` include the two headers?

Comment: The "ain't broke, won't fix" rule.